# Terminal shrinking when it losses focus

Tags: gnome, gnome-terminal, ubuntu-gnome

When losing focus, a tabbed gnome terminal will shrink by one line. A normal (non-tabbed) terminal doesn't have this issue.

What could be causing this? A bug in the application, in the theme or something else?

Video demonstarting this behavior: https://gfycat.com/DearestWealthyBordercollie

Comment: Could be app specific bug. Id suggest you report it to the developers of that terminal.

Comment: Okay, I submitted it to the bug tracker, thanks.